# New capture card YUV 4:2:2 leads to different images

Tags: image-processing

I have just bought a new video capture card whose output format is YUV 4:2:2 (as my old one) and surprisingly when I capture images with both cards I get different results. Differences are very small (have to zoom on edges if you want to see something) but I would like to know where do they come from? I was wondering if it was the transformation:

```
YUV 422 -> YUV 444
```

That could change from one driver to another?

Here is the original image:
[image]

Here is the capture with my old card:
[image]

Here is the capture with my new card:
[image]

Comment: What is the input format to each capture card?  Analog RGB, or ???

Answer (score 1):

4:2:2 means the color information has half the horizontal sample rate compared to the luminance.  Depending on the input, this lower sample rate may require having a low pass filter in the color channels.  Different cards may use different filters in phase and frequency response, resulting in slightly different results near any sharp transitions.